# flutter List not printing out all data in the list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

They are exactly 665 items in my database(firestore) I can query and print all 665 items to the console but when I put them inside a list and print out the list, I am only seeing 60 items. Here is my code

```
getOnlineUsersContact() async {
  List<String> list = [];
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('userPhones')
      .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("phoneNumbers")
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs)  {
      String phoneNumber = doc['number'];
      list.add(phoneNumber);
      print("Mycontact: $phoneNumber"); // prints all 665 items
    }
  });
  print("Mycontact: $list"); // prints only 60 items
}
```

Have I exceeded the maximum data size limit of the list? What could go wrong?

Comment: debugPrint still cut it to 60

Comment: I need the data to be complete in the arraylist

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things:

First, get your querySnapshot:

```dart
final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('userPhones')
      .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("phoneNumbers")
      .get();
```

Then, you need to work with Future.forEach() to await to iterate through all the items on list

```dart
List list = [];

await Future.forEach(querySnapsho.docs, (element) async {
// add to list
});
```

And, once you await to fill the list, you can print.

It will be like this:

```dart
final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('userPhones')
      .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("phoneNumbers")
      .get();
    
List list = [];

await Future.forEach(querySnapsho.docs, (element) async {
// add to list
});

print(list);
```

It is occurring because you aren't waiting for the inside then() callback. All inside then() will be completed in some time in the future that you aren't waiting for.

Comment: Thank you but the above code does not work because I need to target a specific field in the database. Example: String phoneNumber = doc['number']; // this line is not working